# Why are moderators ignoring or declining something that I flagged?

Tags: discussion

A user flagged [this comment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73691/how-to-set-allowunlimitedcontractsize-in-ganache-v2-1-0-with-windows-10#comment89667_73691) "Ganache is currently on v6.5.1. Why on earth are you using v2.1.0?" as unfriendly or unkind.

A moderator disagreed. Why?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @eth, The tools provided for admins to handle such cases are not that helpful.

But, we can take a different action in this situation instead just declining the flag. The user behind the referenced comment is known for commenting in such "a rude" way and has his comments often flagged as offensive. Therefore, we can send him a message to point out [the code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and issuing him an alert to avoid unfriendly comments.

As a moderator, I tolerate a high level of rude/offensive behavior as in my opinion the commenter's intention is to help, but when other users flag a comment as offensive I can't just apply the same level of acceptance. Therefore, I would delete flagged comments if they don't provide much help!!

Comment: Good idea on this specific case. (I don't know if the commenting user was already contacted.)

Comment: I don't think he was contacted. Let's give him a chance, one more flagged comment and we drop him a message.

Comment: FYI here are others that were flagged: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74522/contract-fallback-function-with-erc20/74536#comment90767_74536  and  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74470/web3-can-i-call-a-library-function-without-a-contract#comment90651_74470

Comment: ironically no good vibes in these comments. would you want to take care of it?

Answer (score 3):

As a moderator, I can share with you that the tools we have are very blunt.

For comments, the only options we have are: Delete | Edit | Decline

Most of the time, it is this moderator's opinion that using Delete is too heavyhanded: at worst it can be abused as censorship. Usually, only harmful material is deleted: a clear example of this would be a link to malware, or phishing, or scam site. (Note: moderators are not perfect, and sometimes it is a judgment call. Personally, it has been very rare to face a very difficult judgment call.)

Thus, most of the time, the Decline option would be used. (If there was profanity, maybe the Edit option would be used. Note: moderators also have limited time like everyone else.)

It is for these similar reasons, that questions that are flagged as not an answer, are sometimes or often untouched. The remedy for these situations is (for the community) to downvote and/or leave a comment. When there are enough downvotes, after a few days it will get auto-deleted.